# VIM caught deadly signal SEGV when opening PHP script

Tags: linux, vim, php

I have PHP file on my virtual Linux CentOS machine and intermittently when I open it I am getting right away

Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV

Vim: Finished. Segmentation fault.

I tested that file many times there are no any kind of hidden special characters. More over if I open another PHP file or for that matter any file and open my troubled file from it (:e file_name) I can view it, edit and save without any problems.

I obviously tried vim -u NONE . However this problem limited to one particular PHP file. All other I can edit without any problems. Of course, there might be more files like that, I did not edit every single PHP file in our system.

Any suggestions what is wrong with that file and how to fix it?

Comment: Is there any chance you could upload that PHP script somewhere for us to look at?

Comment: It seems you mean edit, but to be clear here: when you say "open it" do you mean "execute it" or "edit it"? It sounds like there may actually be binary data in there killing it. If you can load it in some manner "from another file" OK, try exporting or copy'pasting using that version to a new file.